# Program that renames mp3 files using ID3 tag

Tags: mp3, filenames, batch-rename

I know a lot of people who have MP3 collections and find out their music directory looks a lot like this...

> 0.mp3
>
> 1.mp3
>
> 2.mp3
>
> 3.mp3
>
> ...

So useless with a file manager.

What is a freeware program that I can download that will rename the files using the ID3 tag information? Also it's important that I can customize how the file name structure will be...e.g. not "01 - Artist - Song - Album" because if it does that then it would be useless.

Comment: Google "Easytag", it does what you want. I'm not putting this as an answer as product recommendations are off topic on stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [EasyTag](https://projects.gnome.org/easytag/)

> - Ability to rename files and directories from the tag (using masks) or by
>     loading a text file

Answer (score 0):

A more lightweight alternative to [EasyTag](https://projects.gnome.org/easytag/) is [Audio Tag Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tagtool/). It also allows you to rename files according to a custom pattern defined from the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard). That's what I've used in the past as it can rename by tags, or if the file has no tags, it will tag the file and then rename it.